# Java Postfix Calculator Error

Tags: java, stack, postfix-mta

I am using a stack to create a postfix calculator in java. I have got the main part written however I am coming across some problems. For starters, I have to account for whitespace, and I am not sure how to do that with my current set up. I am not sure if that will totally fix the program, but it would be a start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Stack;
 public class Postfix 
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Postfix expression");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    Stack<Integer> Pstack = new Stack<Integer>();
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length();i++)
    {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);

        if(ch>='0' && ch<='9')
        {
            Pstack.push((int)(ch-'0'));
        }
        else
        {
            int o1 = Pstack.pop();
            int o2 = Pstack.pop();

            switch(ch)
            {
            case '+':result=o1+o2;
            break;
            case '-':result=o1-o2;
            break;
            case '/':result=o1/o2;
            break;
            case '*':result=o1*o2;
            }
        }
        Pstack.push(result);
    }
    result = Pstack.pop();
    System.out.println("result: "+ result);
   }
}
```

Comment: Put: `if(ch == ' ') continue;` directly after `char ch = input.charAt(i);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, put

```
if(ch == ' ') continue;
```

directly after

```
char ch = input.charAt(i);
```

This will fix the issue with the whitespace.

Another issue is that

```
Pstack.push(result);
```

is executed **every** time, not just in case an operator has been evaluated.

So this statement should be the last one within the "else" case.

You also have to correct the way how the arguments are popped from the stack.

e.g. if you have the postfix expression 12- (which should evaluate to -1),
2 is on top of the stack and 1 comes after.
In the current solution the result would be 2 -1 as the arguments are retrieved in the wrong order.

So

```
int o1 = Pstack.pop();
int o2 = Pstack.pop();
```

should be corrected to

```
int o2 = Pstack.pop();
int o1 = Pstack.pop();
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Also helped me understand it a little better as well. Great answer!

Comment: After looking at my program again, I do have one more question. I just realized that my calculator only works for numbers under 10. For instance, 1 2 + works and equals 3. However, 1 11 + doesnt and it equals 2 instead. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: in this case one would have to change the format of the postfix string by adding a delimiter separating arguments/operators. Otherwise 111- could be interpreted as both 11 1 - or 1 11 -. Then one could use another Scanner over the input param and retrieve the arguments/operators with it.